# How to load data from file to IBM MQ that run in docker container with qload?

Tags: ibm-mq

I have docker container with IBM MQ broker running. There is file on host containing data from another MQ loaded with qload utility. I need to put that data in my queue, but when I try to `qload -m QM1 -o DEV.QUEUE.1 -f file` I get `Error loading MQAPI DLL  RC(2)`.
I don't understand how qload work and when should I enter admin login and password of my IBM MQ broker.

Comment: If there is a way to convert hex file to file with one readable message in one line, that would solve my problem

Comment: Is the LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to include the MQ lib directory?  The MQ included dspmqmsg utility is able to process qload files generated by the legacy qload support pac, this may work for you.

Comment: Did you run `setmqenv` before using `qload`?

Comment: To provide the user ID and password if you require it to connect to your queue manager, use the `-u` [and `-U` parameters] on `qload`. [Depends on the version of `qload` you are using.

Comment: dmpmqmsg works, but not as I expect it to. I think it tries to read my file as plain text, but it is hex or something

Comment: qload files are plain text, and dmpmqmsg would read the same format file. Perhaps you can update your question to show a little snippet of your file, say the first 10 lines? That would only show the MQMD of the first message so not showing us any confidential in message data. It would help to understand what you are doing. P.S. Did you solve the "Error loading MQAPI DLL" problem or is that still your question?